# while exporting gridview into doc , row data bound changes are not coming in downloaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, ado.net

I'm exporting gridview data into doc file using iTextSharp, everything is coming but
    row data bound changes are not coming .

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=KeywordPositionReport.doc");
        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/doc";


        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
         Report.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

        string strBuilder = stringWrite.ToString();
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

        Response.End();



    }
```

//these events are not changed in downloading

```
protected void GVKeywordReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

added  data binding events , i.e this.fillgridview();
                                   this.PersonPerformance();
before the ---
         Report.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

//complete event

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=KeywordPositionReport.doc");
        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/doc";


        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        this.fillgridview();
        this.PersonPerformance();
         Report.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        string strBuilder = stringWrite.ToString();
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();


    }
```